# Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle -Json

Tags: json, jersey

I downloaded/extracted the latest "Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle". Obviously several jar-files that are available in the previous version "Jersey 1.18 ZIP bundle" aren't there anymore? The one's that I need are those to work with Json data e.g. jersey-json-xxx.jar (ObjectMapper ...). Should I use the 'older' version for Json or does the new version has other options for handling Json?

Thanks.
Guy

Comment: You'll need to include `jersey-media-json-jackson` along with the Jackson jars. Here the dependency page from the manual (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#modules-and-dependencies).

Comment: @Baldy I looked at the manual page with the dependencies, one thing isn't clear: does this mean I need to add, besides the jersey-media-json-jackson jar-file, the 19 jar-files as in "Dependency File Details" on https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.11/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html?

Comment: Depends on your platform. At a minimum you'll need `common`, `server` or `client` (or both), `container` or `connector` (as applicable), `media` (depending on your serializer) and maybe `json-media-multipart` or `jersey-gf-cdi`.

Comment: @Baldy Ok thx. Probably my question was confusing, I meant which Jackson jars dependencies (besides the jersey-media-json-jackson). Thx Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Jackson jars you should need.

```
jackson-core
jackson-annotations
jackson-databind
jackson-jaxrs-base
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider
```

If you use the JAXB annotations, you'll need this, too.

```
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations
```

On the off chance that you're using Glassfish and you need multipart forms, there is a bug in Jersey that causes an NPE on Glassfish 4. In order to fix it, you can use one of the Glassfish promoted builds, version **b08** or later.

Comment: Thx. I'm using Jetty (and in the future also maybe Tomcat). Guy

Comment: I haven't used Jetty but you should be fine using `jersey-container-jetty-http` or `jersey-container-jetty-servlet`. Not sure about Tomcat...

Comment: Thx. Out of curiosity and always interested in learning which container do you use? Thx.

Comment: Glassfish 4, promoted build **b09**. I had been using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 but really wanted some of the CDI fixes (ViewScoped, etc.). Not real happy about it being a promoted build but starting with **b08** version it's been very stable. I'm running behind a load balancer (HAProxy) and auto-reboot the instances weekly and haven't had any problems yet (crosses fingers).

Comment: Ok thx. For using Glassfish 4 I suppose you don't need to install the full/complete Java EE 7 stack? Only the Java EE Web Profile + Glassfish is enough?  Thanks.